# How to explicitly call the default value of a function argument in R?

Tags: r

How can I tell R to use the default value of a function argument without i) omitting the argument in the function call and ii) without knowing what the default value is?

I know I can use the default value of `mean` in `rnorm()`:

```
rnorm(n = 100) # by omitting the argument
# or
rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0) # by including it in the call with the default value
```

But assume I don't know the default value but want to include it explicitly in the function call. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the argument list and default values via:

```
> formals(rnorm)
$n


$mean
[1] 0

$sd
[1] 1
```

`formals("rnorm")` also works. Some simple examples:

```
> rnorm(10,mean = formals(rnorm)$mean)
 [1] -0.5376897  0.4372421  0.3449424 -0.9569394 -1.1459726 -0.6109554  0.1907090  0.2991381 -0.2713715
[10] -1.4462570
> rnorm(10,mean = formals(rnorm)$mean + 3)
 [1] 2.701544 2.863189 1.709289 2.987687 2.848045 5.136735 2.559616 3.827967 3.079658 5.016970
```

Obviously, you could store the result of `formals(rnorm)` ahead of time as well.

Answer (score 1):

As @joran has already pointed out, `formals()` exposes the default values. However, as I understand the question, what you're really after is the construction of the *call expression*. To that end, it is useful to combine `formals()` with `as.call()` to produce the call itself. The following function does just that, by producing a function that produces "argument-completed calls," for a given function name `f`:

```
drop_missing <- function(sig) {
  sig[!sapply(sig, identical, quote(expr =))]
}

complete_call <- function(f) {
  nm <- as.name(f)
  sig <- formals(args(f))
  make_call <- function() {
    args <- match.call()[-1]
    sig[names(args)] <- args
    as.call(c(nm, drop_missing(sig)))
  }
  formals(make_call) <- sig
  make_call
}
```

Example usage:

```
complete_call("log")(1)
#> log(x = 1, base = exp(1))

complete_call("rnorm")(10)
#> rnorm(n = 10, mean = 0, sd = 1)

complete_call("rnorm")()
#> rnorm(mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

Remarks:

1) The output is a language object. To execute the call, you need to evaluate it, e.g.,

```
eval(complete_call("rnorm")(10))
#> [1] -0.89428324 -1.78405483 -1.83972728 ... (output truncated)
```

2) If you want `complete_call()` to accept a function, rather than the name of a function, you could write `nm <- as.name(deparse(substitute(f)))` in place of the given assignment. However, that would not work in a nested call, where you would get `as.name("f")` for `nm`, because of R's rules fo lexical scoping.

3) Without the call to `args()` in the assignment of `sig`, `complete_call()` would only work for closures, since primitive and builtin functions don't have formals.