# Conditionally Override Default Arguments When Passing Masked Variables (in '...') to group_by()

Tags: r, dplyr, parameter-passing, wrapper, tidyeval

## Motivation

I am creating a custom utility function `streak_over()`, which is intended to grammatically mimic the `dplyr` verb `group_by()`. While `streak_over()` essentially wraps the grouping functionality of `group_by()`, this grouping is a precursor to further operations.

Within the context of a given dataset, the purpose of `streak_over()` is to index each "streak" of *consecutive* observations sharing a group, where the grouping is preestablished (via a prior `group_by()`) or specified in `streak_over()` itself (via [tidy evaluation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)).

Here is an illustration, where the grouping variables are `x` and `y` respectively:

```
      x y     group_id streak_index
  <dbl> <chr>    <int>        <int>
1     1 a            1            1
2     1 a            1            1
3     2 b            4            2
4     2 b            4            2
5     1 a            1            3
6     2 a            3            4
7     1 b            2            5
8     2 b            4            6
```

## Details

Aside from one small issue, I have everything working exactly as desired. Here is the general form of `streak_over`, which accepts in `...` all the arguments for `group_by()`, and then returns an `integer` vector (like `streak_index`) with the streak indices. **Note:** `.start` and `.min` are my own parameters that define the criteria for a "streak"; aside from their existence as named parameters in the function header, they are otherwise irrelevant to my question.

```
streak_over <- function(..., .start = 1, .min = 2) {
  return(
    dplyr::group_by(...) # %>%
    # ... %>% Further Operations %>% ...
  )
}
```

Generally, the usability is ideal. Given a `data.frame` like `x` | `y` from the above illustration

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), y = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"))
```

we can generate our vector of streak indices through an ergonomic workflow:

```
df %>% group_by(x, y) %>% streak_over(.add = TRUE)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 6

df %>% group_by(x) %>% streak_over(y, .add = TRUE)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 6

df %>% streak_over(x, y)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 6
```

We can also change the grouping as we would with successive uses of `group_by()`:

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>% streak_over(y, .add = FALSE)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4

df %>% group_by(x) %>% streak_over(y)  # .add = FALSE by default
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4

df %>% streak_over(y)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
```

Finally, we can generate the indices with no grouping whatsoever:

```
df %>% streak_over()  # no grouping given
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

However, there is one default behavior I would like to change.

## Problem

According to the current default (`.add = FALSE`) of the `group_by()` function it wraps, `streak_over()` currently overrides existing groupings when `.add` is not specified otherwise. While I generally **do like** this behavior, there is one situation where it is **counterintuitive and inconvenient**:

```
df %>% group_by(x, y) %>% streak_over()
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Here, a grouping already exists and is likely useful. Furthermore, `streak_over()` contains no further grouping variables, which would otherwise necessitate disambiguation via `.add`. **It would be very convenient to simply have `streak_over()` *preserve* the existing grouping in this particular situation, while deferring to `group_by()` for all other default settings**.

```
df %>% group_by(x, y) %>% streak_over()
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 6
```

Here is tabulated the behavior I desire:

| `.add` | Grouping Variables Specified in `streak_over()` Call | Grouping Variables Unspecified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *(missing)* | Current Default Behavior for `group_by()` | **Always Add to Existing Grouping** |
| `TRUE` | Add to Existing Grouping | Add to Existing Grouping |
| `FALSE` | Override Existing Grouping | Override Existing Grouping |

I also wish this "deferral" to be **dynamic**: if the R team updates `dplyr::group_by()` with new default settings (like `mutate(.add = TRUE,`), I want `streak_over()` to follow suit in alignment with the `dplyr` workflow, rather than having hard-coded defaults (like `streak_over(.add = TRUE,`) that might go out of date.

Finally, for the sake of aesthetics and professionality, I wish to keep the function header for `streak_over()` in roughly canonical form:

```
streak_over <- function(..., .start = 1, .min = 2) {
  # ...
}

# Or...

streak_over <- function(.data, ..., .add, .drop, .start = 1, .min = 2) {
  # ...
}
```

## Attempts

All without success, I have explored many approaches. My current iteration

```
streak_over <- function(.data, ..., .add, .drop,
                        .start = 1, .min = 2) {
  if(rlang::is_missing(.add) && !length(list(...))) {
    .add <- TRUE

    if(!rlang::is_empty(dplyr::group_vars(.data))) {
      message("Existing groups will be kept. Discard with '.add = FALSE'.")
    }
  }
  
  
  return(
         dplyr::group_by(.data, ...,
                         .add = rlang::maybe_missing(.add),
                         .drop = rlang::maybe_missing(.drop)) # %>%
         # ... %>% Further Operations %>% ...
  )
}
```

has failed, along with many others, for what *appear* to be the following reasons:

1. Despite my initial instincts as supported by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684509), `length(list(...))` cannot effectively test for the presence of **masked variables** (like `y` from `df` in `streak_over(y)`), and `match.call(expand.dots = FALSE) == match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)` seems similarly unfeasible. Indeed, the former approach gives me the error below; it seems to interpret `y` as an object unto itself, rather than merely the *symbol* for a variable within `.data`:

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>% streak_over(y)
# Error in streak_over(., y) : object 'y' not found
```

2. It seems that `dplyr` plays poorly with [`rlang::maybe_missing()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/missing_arg.html), whose value *should* simulate a missing argument. Since `group_by()` unconditionally coerces `.add` into a `logical`, I get the following error:

```
streak_over <- function(.data, ..., .add, .drop,
                      .start = 1, .min = 2) {
  # Condition REMOVED to progress beyond error above.
  return(
    dplyr::group_by(.data, ...,
                    .add = rlang::maybe_missing(.add),
                    .drop = rlang::maybe_missing(.drop)) # %>%
    # ... %>% Further Operations %>% ...
  )
}
```

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>% streak_over(y)
# Error in if (.add) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

3. Even when I attempted to collapse the function header (`streak_over(..., .start = 1, .min = 2)`), and let `.add` "lurk in the shadows" until it is explicitly specified (`streak_over(.add = TRUE,`), I had to alter its value *somehow*: `new_add <- TRUE` conditionally, followed by `group_by(..., .add = new_add)`. Unfortunately, if the user *does* explicitly specify `.add`, R will include it within `...` next to `.add = new_add`, and the resulting clash cannot be avoided by assigning `new_add <- NULL` where appropriate. The result is the (admittedly predictable) error:

```
streak_over <- function(..., .start = 1, .min = 2) {
  # Check if '.add' is present in '...'; and if no masked variables are present therein.
  if(is.null(list(...)$.add) && all(names(list(...)) %in% c(".data", ".add", ".drop"))) {
    new_add <- TRUE
  } else {
    new_add <- NULL
  }
  
  return(
    dplyr::group_by(..., .add = new_add) # %>%
    # ... %>% Further Operations %>% ...
  )
}
```

```
df %>% group_by(x, y) %>% streak_over(.add = FALSE)
# Error in dplyr::group_by(..., .add = add) : 
#  formal argument ".add" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

## Conclusion

I feel like there *has* to be a way to conditionally override the default value of a formal parameter to a wrapped function, even if it is the enigmatic `...` containing masked or tidily evaluated variables. However, I suspect this verges into `symbol` territory, an area of R with which I am decidedly inexperienced.

As always, I appreciate your consideration, along with any assistance you might be able to render.

---

## Update

Thanks to the [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68181832/timeline#history_a2925461-4aee-414c-a2da-13eac35d89d0) from [ktiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7010056), synthesized with [further research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118105) on Stack Overflow, I have cobbled together a somewhat "hacky" solution, which seems to satisfy my initial criteria:

```
streak_over <- function(.data, ..., .add, .drop,
                        .start = 1, .min = 2) {
  # Store the defaults for 'group_by()', in case they are needed.
  gb_formals <- formals(dplyr::group_by)
  
  # If neither '.add' nor masked variables in '...' were supplied to
  # 'streak_over()', yet a grouping already exists in '.data', override the
  # 'group_by()' default to intuitively preserve the grouping.
  if(rlang::is_missing(.add) && !length(rlang::enquos(...)) &&
     !rlang::is_empty(dplyr::group_vars(.data))) {
    .add <- TRUE
    message("Existing groups will be kept. Discard with '.add = FALSE'.")
  }

  return(
    dplyr::group_by(.data, ...,
                    .add = rlang::maybe_missing(.add, gb_formals$.add),
                    .drop = rlang::maybe_missing(.drop, gb_formals$.drop)) # %>%
    # ... %>% Further Operations %>% ...
  )
}
```

I would welcome any further help that:

- Offers a more elegant solution; possibly (say) as suggested [here](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2018/04/11/changing-the-default-arguments-to-a-function/#use-the-default-package) with the [`default`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/default/default.pdf) package, which seems **ideally surgical** if implemented safely...though I *do* wonder if the masking will translate properly.
  Unfortunately, my first attempt failed: while everything looks clean

```
streak_over <- function(..., .start = 1, .min = 2) {
  # Condition always TRUE here to illustrate the point.
  if(TRUE) {
    default::default(group_by) <- list(.add = TRUE)
  }
  
  # Print out default, to check if correctly updated.
  default::default(group_by)
  
  return(
    group_by(...) # %>%
    # ... %>% Further Operations %>% ...
  )
}
```

and the printout indicates that `.add` now defaults to `TRUE` for the local `group_by()`, the output still acts as if `.add = FALSE`:

```
df %>% group_by(x, y) %>% streak_over()
#   - .data = [none]
#   - ... = [none]
# * - .add = TRUE
#   - .drop = group_by_drop_default(.data)

# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

- Improves the technique (tools, structure, syntax, etc.) of my existing solution; possibly (say) by using `rlang::fn_fmls()` instead of `base::formals()`.
- Stabilizes the functionality of this solution; especially to be more robust against structural changes to `dplyr::group_by()`, including but not limited to:

  - the alteration of existing defaults for parameters in `group_by()`
  - the addition of defaults for parameters in `group_by()` that previously had no defaults
  - the renaming of existing parameters in `group_by()`
  - the addition of new parameters to `group_by()`.

In addition to answers meeting the original criteria, any answers that successfully provide this further help (while meeting the original criteria) will receive my upvote and consideration for acceptance.

### Bonus

I am also curious as to which of the following `streak_over()` headers is more canonical:

- `streak_over(..., .start = 1, .min = 2)`: typical wrapper.
- `streak_over(..., .add, .start = 1, .min = 2)`: [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68181832/timeline#history_a2925461-4aee-414c-a2da-13eac35d89d0) by [ktiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7010056).
- `streak_over(.data, ..., .add, .drop, .start = 1, .min = 2)`: resembles `dplyr`.

Mind you, this function is intended to mimic the `dplyr` grammar, in imitation of `group_by(.data, ..., .add, .drop)`. Yet before performing further operations, `streak_over()` still wraps another function: a situation in which R overwhelmingly represents all arguments passed to the wrapped function as `...` in the wrapper header. Then again, for purely functional purposes, `.add` is the only formal parameter passed to `group_by()` that need explicitly exist outside `...` in the `streak_over()` header.

Clarity on this point, as supported by authoritative references, might serve as a "tiebreaker" for acceptance of an answer.

Thanks again! — Greg

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided some test cases that could be run to verify possible solutions. It's unclear exactly what command you are running when you get your errors. The code you have provided so far does not return the results shown in the question. We don't need your actual function, just a simple reproducible example that can be used to test the particular problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, and thanks for reading!  The thing about this question is that it is essentially conceptual in nature: "how do I wrap `group_by()` with a function of the form `streak_by(..., .start, .min)` (or `streak_by(.data, ..., .add, .drop, .start, .min)`), such that I can override the default for `.add` when and only when `...` (which may contain **tidily evaluated** and masked variables) and `.add` are both missing, and otherwise preserve the current defaults for `group_by()`?". The particulars of what I do _after_ the grouping are irrelevant; they are merely the motivation.

Comment: So to that end, the function `streak_over <- function(..., .start = 1, .min = 2){return(dplyr::group_by(...))}` should suffice, or alternatively `streak_over <- function(.data, ..., .add, .drop, .start = 1, .min = 2){return(dplyr::group_by(...))}`.  All I really need is a way to conditionally override the current defaults for `group_by()`, while otherwise preserving them, to get the grouping behavior defined in the table and illustrated in the example output.

Comment: @MrFlick  I have updated my question with reproducible errors. To be clear, these are examples of errors I have already diagnosed, and their cause is hardly mysterious. However, since they concretely illustrate the conceptual roadblocks to a solution, so I suppose they do serve a conceptual purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that

1. uses `rlang::enquos()` to defuse the function arguments in `...`,
2. supplies `.add = TRUE` in cases where

   - `.add` is not explicitly passed AND
   - `...` contains only one "non-special-dot" argument (the name of the data, or `.` in a pipe)
3. calls a custom wrapper for `group_by()` with those variables:

```
streak_over <- function(..., .start = 1, .min = 2) {
  defused <- rlang::enquos(...)
  if (any(".add" %in% names(defused),
          sum(! grepl("\\..+", names(defused))) > 1))
    custom_wrapper(...)
  else
    custom_wrapper(..., .add = TRUE)
}

custom_wrapper <- function(...) {
  # add custom logic here
  dplyr::group_by(...)
}
```

Note that I did not go out of my way to match all the cases you specified, but this might work as a proof of concept that you can roll into a more fully fledged solution.

Trying it out:

#### Example 1

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   streak_over()
```

keeps the grouping:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   x [2]
      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     1 a    
3     2 b    
4     2 b    
5     1 a    
6     2 a    
7     1 b    
8     2 b
```

#### Example 2

```
df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  streak_over(y)
```

overwrites the grouping:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   y [2]
      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     1 a    
3     2 b    
4     2 b    
5     1 a    
6     2 a    
7     1 b    
8     2 b
```

#### Example 3

```
df %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   streak_over(.add = F)
```

deletes the grouping:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     1 a    
3     2 b    
4     2 b    
5     1 a    
6     2 a    
7     1 b    
8     2 b
```

#### Example 4

```
df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  streak_over(y, .add = T)
```

adds the grouping:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   x, y [4]
      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     1 a    
3     2 b    
4     2 b    
5     1 a    
6     2 a    
7     1 b    
8     2 b
```

Comment: Thanks, @ktiu, I am exploring this as we speak!

Comment: Just FYI, I _do_ want to avoid hard-coding any defaults for the `group_by()` parameters when creating the function header `streak_over <- function(..., .add` **`= F`** `, .start = 1, .min = 2)`. The reason is that the R team might change the defaults for `group_by()` in the future, and I want `streak_over()` to automatically align with these changes. Hence, I want to achieve what `rlang::maybe_missing()` should have done, without throwing the error (#2) in my list of examples.

Comment: I updated my answer, see if the new approach satisfies your constraints.

Comment: Thanks @ktiu, I will check it out!

Comment: Due to the regex, I think there's an edge case in your new `streak_over()`: for `streak_over(.data = df %>% group_by(x), y)`, it **fails to override existing groups**. As a named parameter, `.data` appears in `names(defused)` as `".data"` rather than `""`, which reduces by 1 the count of nonmatches to the regex `"\\..+"`. As such, when only one masking variable is specified alongside `.data`, the count of nonmatches comes out to only 1. So when `.add` is also left out, the `if` condition is `FALSE` and the `else` statement is executed, which passes `.add = TRUE` to `group_by()`.

Comment: Likewise `df %>% group_by(x) %>% streak_over_2(.data = ., y)`, all with or without explicitly naming `, .drop =` (anything) `)`.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering how this version of `streak_over()` would check if a grouping exists in the given `.data`; I do so in my hacked solution, because I don't want to confuse the user with `message("Existing groups will be kept. Discard with '.add = FALSE'.")`, unless there actually _were_ some groups to begin with. If `.data` is not a formal argument in the `streak_over()` function header, then `length(dplyr::group_vars(x = .data)) > 0` cannot check for the presence of grouping variables, as `group_vars()` cannot accept an `rlang_fake_data_pronoun` object, only a `data.frame` (or extension).